# XCode: Clear UISegmentedControl

Tags: xcode, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I have two questions. If someone could provide some sample code with the answer that would be greatly appreciated.

1. Is there a one liner to delete all the segments in a UISegmentedControl? (I was planning to do the below in a loop, but that seemed a bit tedious)

`[selectionSegment removeSegmentAtIndex:0 animated:NO];
[selectionSegment removeSegmentAtIndex:1 animated:NO];
.
.
.`

1. I want to add 10 elements to the cleared control, initially I was going to do the following, is there a better solution?

`[Segment insertSegmentWithTitle:@"title" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[Segment insertSegmentWithTitle:@"title1" atIndex:1 animated:NO];
[Segment insertSegmentWithTitle:@"title2" atIndex:2 animated:NO];
[Segment insertSegmentWithTitle:@"title3" atIndex:3 animated:NO];`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look into the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html). There is a method `removeAllSegments` which answers your first question and an initializer `initWithItems` which could be the answer for your second question.